# Problem connecting two RS232

Tags: rs232

I have a device with a RS232 communication port (3 pin,tx,rx and gnd).

When I connect it to a PC RS232, they don't communicate together.

I use hyper terminal on the PC side and all setting are correct.
Why it doesn't work? Do I need pull up or pull down resistors?

Comment: The problem is that the device doesn't have a RS-232 port, it has a TTL UART port. And you may have destroyed it by connecting them together.

Comment: no, connection port in device side is RS232, for example voltage in rx line is -6.2

Comment: Is Tx of Controller connected to Rx of PC?? Which is your microcontroller??

Comment: no,It is not a microcontroller , it is output a device that is RS232

Comment: @user3577549 Wait... What?? What device? And still Tx of "device" is connected to Rx of PC?

Comment: ABB aquamaster , yes tx of device is connect to rx and rx device is connect to tx

Comment: Why are you convinced all settings are correct? What are the settings exactly and can you point us to the manual where these settings are described?

Comment: Because: 1-There is no special configuration!! 2-both is rs232 and they should be connected to each other with wire!! 3- setting in pc side is :parity and bauderate and flow control and stop bit And connection method that Specified in the catalog!!

Comment: 90% of the problems related to RS232 (or UART) is inversion of RX and TX wire somewhere. Try to swap them and try again.

Comment: With a 3 wire RS232 connection the only possible flow control settings are "None", "Xon/Xoff", or shorting certain pins on the external device.  Which are you using?

Comment: i test this and other (for example RS232 ISOLATOR) but do not work ,,power supply is 9 volt in this device ,do this power supply will not create any problem ?

Comment: @Nedd ,yes and i set on NONE! AND shorting certain pins are 1-4-6 & 7-8 on a 9 pin D.

Comment: Are you able to connect a known working RS232 device up to the same PC RS232 output and have working communications - both ways?  (That would eliminate that side of the issue.)  After this the only possible course of action may be to show us a schematic or data sheet on what you are trying to connect to.

Comment: i use of RS232 PC side Without any problems for show data on lcd connected to microcontroller , so pc side do not have nay problem .. device have a interface that is ISOLATOR ,I can connect to device with it , so device side do not problem too.. this aquamaster is older version of ABB and do not support , for datasheet see below link , page 17         http://www.datasheetarchive.com/dl/Datasheets-SW22/DSASW00424227.pdf

Comment: As I said this version longer is not supported ,for this i upload user manual with communicated method for it , 
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=04619339026975548868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the ISOLATOR output connections from the device then your signals are likely being converted to DC RS232 signals (and inverted) rather then being normal bipolar RS232 signals.  Note that the ISOLATOR side also needs power and gnd inputs and likely a pull up resistor above the transistor collector.

So basically if that is the arrangement you have the voltages from/to your device are not compatible with the voltages from/to your PC.

If you connect the ISOLATOR collector pins to a pull up resistor at +5, and the emitters pins to gnd you can use a chip like a MAX232 to convert the collector signals back into the required voltages that match the requirement of the PC.

I was not able to access the tinyupload.

Did you add the power, gnd, and resistor parts as above?  Are you using another chip like a MAX232 to reconvert the DC signals to be PC compatible?

If you still need to add the conversion circuit between the ISOLATOR side and the PC you may need to implement something similar to one of these:

http://www.qsl.net/ct1efl/rs232_cct.gif

http://www.pkfamily.com/users/solson/eeg/isoRS232.gif

You didn't mention if you needed to send data from the PC back to the device.  If not then you may only need part of the circuit linked above.

Comment: thank in advance @Nedd
I use of isolator that bought of store and I do not know the internal circuit , but i test between two pc and that work . 
in your opinion , Connection can not be created without isolator(Because the power supply is diffrent)!? if yes, do  there is this problem for communicate device with the pc?

you can use of this link instead tinyupload  : http://wikisend.com/download/971802/AquaMaster Service edition 2.pdf

Comment: I think that is solved my problem with the circuit that you offer ..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the TX goes into RX and the RX goes into TX. Most most forget this.

Also, confirm if ground connection is solid.

Comment: i test this and other (for example RS232 ISOLATOR) but do not work ,,power supply is 9 volt in this device ,do this power supply will not create any problem ? There's your answer in the above comments

Answer (score 0):

Software running through PC serial ports can require either hardware or software flow control and often that means "tying back" the pins for these, if the device you are plugging in does not do that.

Additionally, serial ports are infamous for protocol issues. Does the software require a set baud rate? Parity? Seven bits or eight? If the wiring is right but the protocols are wrong, it still won't work.

If you said what the device was, and what the software was, and confirmed that it was an actual serial port not a USB serial emulator, the problem might be easier to find. Serial ports are not complicated--if you have all the data for what both sides require.

Comment: There's your answers in the above comments